# Is this partial derivative correct?

Tags: derivatives

[image]

I think that the $-x_1$ in the underlined segment should be a $-x_3$, unless I am understanding the notation wrong.

Comment: yes you are right it should be $-x_3$ instead of $-x_1$ @anna

Comment: You are right ! One more typo in a textbook.

Comment: Could not withhold myself to have a look at your profile and noticed that I am not the only one in this. Your number of "profile-looks" almost doubles your reputation. Nice picture!